# Equivalent of C# "static variable" in Java

Tags: c#, java, static

In C# I can declare a static var in a class. E.g : to count the create instances of class "foo". Like so

```
class foo
{
    static int countFoo =0;

    public foo()
    {
        countFoo++;
    }
}
```

Now - for each foo created I can use a `getFooCount` method to know how many instances were created. 
How do you do that in Java? 
I tried to do the same and it doesn't work.
Please explain why and how. Thanks!

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints - whenever you've got code that doesn't work, you should include it in your question.

Comment: your code should be corrected as  

class foo
{
     static int countFoo =0;

     public foo()
     {
         countFoo++;
     }
} // closing part is missing this may be  your problem 

hope this will work for you

Comment: This counter implementation is obviously not threadsafe.

Comment: 'Doesn't work' how? It is legal Java code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can do exactly the same and it *will* work. Sample code:

```
class Foo
{
    private static int count;

    Foo()
    {
        count++;
    }

    static void printCount()
    {
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Foo.printCount(); // 0
        Foo foo1 = new Foo();
        Foo foo2 = new Foo();
        Foo.printCount(); // 2        
    }
}
```

(It would have helped if you'd shown what you'd tried...)

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Java (though its not thread safe)

```
class Foo { 
    static int countFoo =0;

    public Foo() {
        countFoo++;
    }
}
```

What exactly is the problem you are having?